# How can I round numbers with unknown constants on Python

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

I'm having problems with a project.
I want any number that multiplies with G (or G**yyy)with less precision than 0,5e-14 to be equal to 0.
I don't know how I can round a number next to a unknown constant.

I tried:
 - the function round(x1,14),didn't work, gave me "type Add doesn't define **round** method"
 - the

```py
Input: x0=0.025*G-4.03
x1=x0-(((func.subs(x,x0))**2)/(func.subs(x,x0+func.subs(x,x0))-func.subs(x,x0)))
print(simplify(x1)-x0)

Output: -0.025*G + 4.03 + 1.0*(3.94430452610506e-31*G**10 + 1.81753552562921e-27*G**9 - 7.10858338912758e-25*G**8 - 1.52201232709757e-22*G**7 + 4.2351647362715e-22*G**6 - 2.02610280983229e-18*G**5 + 3.53883589099269e-16*G**4 - 2.39530617562878e-14*G**3 + 6.21724893790087e-13*G**2 + 1660.85701907689*G - 266416.790310032)/(5.16987882845642e-26*G**8 - 1.73707928636136e-23*G**7 - 3.3881317890172e-21*G**6 + 9.75781955236954e-19*G**5 - 5.55111512312578e-17*G**4 + 4.66293670342566e-15*G**3 - 1.4210854715202e-13*G**2 + 6.82121026329696e-12*G + 66434.2807630764
```

I want any number that multiplies with G (or G**yyy)with less precision than 0,5e-14 to be equal to 0.

For example
what I have: 3.94430452610506e-31*G**10
I want this to presented as: 0